# Как сформировать запрос в БД MySql что бы записанные в столбец данные выводились построчно?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть форма на сайте и БД в phpmyadmin c таблицей.
В таблице несколько полей - столбцов, в одном из которых данные занесены построчно, через нажатие enter.
То есть в поле textarea, в форме вносится построчно состав, и каждая новая позиция состава с новой строки после нажатия enter.
В БД, в столбце, данные отображаются построчно, то есть новая позиция с новой строки.
Можно ли выводить данные из одного столбца так, как они в него внесены, то есть построчно.

Запись в таблицу происходит стандартным запросом.

```
"INSERT INTO table (name, description) VALUES (%(name)s,%(description)s)
```

Comment: Выложите: CREATE TABLE таблицы, INSERT INTO с примером данных (3-5 записей), требуемый результат запроса, точную версию MySQL.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю. Вроде выложил. Переменные принимают данные из формы.